# How to change field display order using radDataForm with JSON source

Tags: json, vue.js, nativescript

Using Vue.js / NativeScript (radDataForm) I want to reorder the display of the fields when using JSON as a source. My current code works, but the display is:

1. Album Name
2. Band Name
3. Owned
4. Year
5. Borrowed

Which is not the order in the code.

I'm aware of this:

```
<df:EntityProperty name="albumName" displayName="Name of Album" index="0" />
```

but, **how do I add `index="0"`to my JSON object?**

Also - I don't know what this does?

```
str: "",
bool: false
```

Sample Code:

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="JSON example" class="action-bar" />
            <RadDataForm :source="album" />
    </Page>
</template>

    <script>
        import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
        import RadDataForm from "nativescript-ui-dataform/vue";
        Vue.use(RadDataForm);

        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    album: {
                        bandName: "Beatles",
                        albumName: "Seargent Peppers",
                        year: "2017",
                        owned: true,
                        borrowed: true
                    },
                    str: "",
                    bool: false
                };
            }
        };
    </script>
```

#### iPhone Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you could control `index` from `source` but you can do that using `metadata`.

**Example**

```
<template>
  <Page class="page">
    <ActionBar title="JSON example" class="action-bar" />
    <RadDataForm :source="album" :metadata="metadata" />
  </Page>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
    import RadDataForm from "nativescript-ui-dataform/vue";
    Vue.use(RadDataForm);

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                album: {
                    bandName: "Beatles",
                    albumName: "Seargent Peppers",
                    year: "2017",
                    owned: true,
                    borrowed: true
                },
                metadata: {
"isReadOnly": false,
"propertyAnnotations":
    [
        {
            "name": "bandName",
            "index": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "albumName",
            "index": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "year",
            "index": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "owned",
            "index": 4
        },
        {
            "name": "myRating",
            "index": 3
        }
    ]
}
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks... that bit of code you provided will do everything I wanted to do... I can also use ` displayName: "Name of Album" ` in the metadata.  I looked for a long time for a solution, but I couldn't find one. I'm going to do an example of this with local storage.  Much appreciated!

Comment: I also have learned that `"isReadOnly": false,` will apply to all fields if placed at the top. Nice!